# PHP com MongoDB - Como criar sessão no MongoDB e executar comando na mesma?

Tags: php, mongodb

Criei uma conexão com mongodb e criei uma sessão a partir da mesma:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$sessao = $manager->startSession();
$id_sessao = $sessao->getLogicalSessionId();
```

No código acima eu sei que a sessão foi criada com sucesso, pois se eu mandar imprimir o objeto $id_sessao, o id é mostrado. Mas agora quero executar um "find()" nessa sessão. Pra isso estou tentando extrair o "server" pra tentar executar nele o comando "find":

```
$busca_vendas = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['find'=>'vendas','query'=>[]]);
$cursor = $sessao->getServer()->executeCommand("loja",$busca_vendas);
```

Porém, no código acima, a função getServer() retorna NULL. Dai não consigo executar o FIND dentro da sessão. Estou fazendo certo?

Answer (score 0):

Acabei encontrando outro jeito de fazer. Descobri que dá pra especificar a sessao ao realizar o executeQuery(). Porém ainda acho estranho, na minha tentativa anterior, o getServer() retornar vazio. Mas em todo caso, assim deu certo:

```
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([],[]);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("loja.vendas",$query,['session'=>$sessao]);
```